# App crashes when InterstitialAd is loaded

Tags: android, admob

When installing Unity Ads- mediation the app crashes after InterstitialAd is loaded !
The only way to fix it is to change the gradle file   implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.7.2.0'
From 3.7.2.0 to 3.6.0.0  so it can support the old Google Mobile Ads sdk.
I use native ads SDK and that installs play-services-ads:19.5.0 which is old and this might be the problem
(  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0')

Because play-services-ads version 20 changed the InterstitialAd class to the namespace "com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial" (previously it was in namespace "com.google.android.gms.ads").

What should I do?

`Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd; Error AndroidRuntime    at com.google.unity.ads.Interstitial$1.run(Interstitial.java:69) Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file cFgPBRjZOA6VSPmpMc_bvQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]] 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    ... 8 more 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64)  2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:764) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6123) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:238) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1787) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 2021/08/20 09:34:23.975 24258 24258 Error AndroidRuntime        ... 5 more`

Comment: can you update question with error log?

Comment: I don't think the error itself is relevant since I already wrote my assumption as to what causes the issue. But I added the log now in any case. thanks